# Why does IgnorePatternWhitespace break regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Dummy 1 and 2 doesn't throw an exception but dummy 3 does. Also it appears dummy2 doesnt run my regex right (judging from the longer real version). Why are any of these different? The first has no whitespace in the pattern and the other two should have the whitespace ignored creating the same pattern

Having it all one line works perfectly but is harder to read and edit.

```
    Regex dummy1 = new Regex(@"(^\s*#(?<test>.*))", RegexOptions.Compiled );
    Regex dummy2 = new Regex(@"(^\s*#(?<test>.*)
)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    Regex dummy3 = new Regex(@"(^\s*#(?<test>.*))", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: what exception dummy 3 is throwing?

Comment: @Rui when the question directly relates to whitespace, removing a newline can break the question ;p

Comment: @MicrosoftDN "Not enough )'s."

Comment: Ok ok my mistake sorry about that! I think I need a coffee :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

> **IgnorePatternWhitespace** Eliminates unescaped white space from the pattern and enables comments marked with #...

Everything from the `#` (inclusive) is considered a comment

This is true in the second example too, but in that case the `)` on the next line balances the `(` on the first line.

So the second regex pattern is actually `(^\s*)` - and the third is `(^s*` - which is invalid.

You probably want to replace your `#` with `\#`.